# OPTIONS/HEAD REST API request with Okhttp3

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I`m writing some Rest client on Android and I met a problem - I have no idea how to make HEAD and OPTIONS requests.

There are no problems with GET/POST/PUT/DELETE/PATCH requests in OkHttp3, basically they looks like:

```
        request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .headers(headerBuilder.build())
                .post(bodyBuilder.build())
                .build();
```

And OkHttp3 doesnt provide additional methods like head() or option().

So how can I make HEAD and OPTIONS requests using OkHttp3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found answer, may be it will be useful for someone else

OkHttp3 still has method

```
Builder method(String method, RequestBody body)
```

So OPTIONS requests looks like

```
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .headers(headerBuilder.build())
                .method("OPTIONS",requestBody)
                .build();
```

same for HEAD

Answer (score 9):

It appears (at least in the [current implementation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Request.Builder.html#head--), `API 3.12.0`), `HEAD` request can be made just like `GET` and others:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .head()
                .build();
```

`OPTION` still has to be implemented using `.method()`